# Chaining string operations on Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I recently found out about the `str` method for Pandas series and it's great! However if I want to chain operations (say, a couple `replace` and a `strip`) I need to keep calling `str` after every operation, making it not the most elegant code.

For example, lets say my column names contain spaces and periods and I want to replace them by underscores. I might also want to strip any leftover underscores. If I wanted to do this using `str` methods, is there any way of avoiding having to run:

`df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('.', '_').str.strip('_')`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you opposed to using regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think need `str` repeat for each `.str` function, it is per design.

---

But here is possible use only one `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['aa dd', 'dd.d_', 'd._'])

print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [aa dd, dd.d_, d._]
Index: []

print (df.columns.str.replace('[\s+.]', '_').str.strip('_'))
Index(['aa_dd', 'dd_d', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a list comprehension?

```
import re
df.columns = [re.sub('[\s.]', '_', x).strip('_') for x in df.columns]
```

In a list comp, you're working with the string object directly, without the need to call `.str` each time.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, list comprehensions can get us to the same answer but I was just curious if we could chain str operations together

Comment: @tomasn4a You already knew the answer to that ;) Your current code does chain them.

Comment: Right, but I wanted to know if there was a way of not having to type `str` after every operation, while still making use of `str`.

Comment: @tomasn4a With a list comp :) And you _can_ collapse replace calls only, not others.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my two cents to improve the answers:

> I was just curious if we could chain str operations together

We would like to have something like `tweet.str.replace('@',).strip().lower()`.
In fact, we could hope that a chain of operations can be even further optimized (compiled) into something like `tweet.str.replace_strip_lower_combined`.

While this is perfectly reasonable, the current API **only processes one operation at a time** and doesn't support such combining.

> Why not to use list comprehensions

Because of performance: `pd.Series.str` offers [vectorized string functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html).